# More than one unit root

Tags: unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm wondering how to detect the existence of more than one unit root. I've tested the non-stationnarity of my serie using the strategy of test of Dickey-Fuller (joint hypothesis: Fisher), and I detect  unit root. however, after differencing the serie, I think that it's still non stationary and it has another unit root.
My questions are:

1. How can I detect more than one unit root
2. Am i obliged to apply the strategy of Fisher of Dickey-fuller again to the differienced serie or since I did not detect a trend in the level serie I'll not detect it in the differencing one?

Comment: Point 2. is correct: you apply ADF test repeatedly but you normally discard the possibility for trend or constant for higher-order unit roots (no trend for root number two, no trend or intercept for higher order roots).

Comment: So if I understand well, i apply the test of DF to the differiencied serie to detect the second unit root ?

Comment: Yes, you do that.